# Does optical density depend upon concentration of a solution?

Tags: photons, density, optical-materials

Does optical density vary upon the amount of salts dissolved in water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  You can easily test this by, for example, filling a glass test tube with water and measuring the focal length of the resulting cylindrical lens.  Add greater and greater concentrations of salts to the water and you will see that the focal length varies with concentration.